# Setting HttpOnly Cookies with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I need the access tokens to be stored as HTTP Only Cookies (they cannot be accessible to JavaScript). There doesn't seem to be much documentation on this, and Amplify doesn't have a way to support this functionality (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8147).

AWS has a blog post on implementing this (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/reduce-risk-by-implementing-httponly-cookie-authentication-in-amazon-api-gateway/), but they assume the hosted UI is being used. I want to run my own sign-in page, but I'm not sure how to do this otherwise. Also, there will be no third-party services used.

As of now, I'm thinking I should setup an API Gateway endpoint inputting username, password, and any relevant user pool information that will invoke a Lambda function. The Lambda function will use the SDK to authenticate the user and then return the necessary access and refresh tokens as HTTP Only Cookies with the body merely indicating the log in was successful.

However, this approach seems needlessly convoluted. Is there a better way to programmatically log in with JavaScript and have the tokens returned as HTTP Only Cookies without the client code ever having direct access to them?

Comment: did you find out how to do this?